# Creating controls but not adding it to the form, how does it affect performance?

Tags: vb.net, performance, optimization

This question is not regarding coding help but more of an understanding of Visual Basics. If I were to programmatically create new controls and assign properties to them like so...

```
Dim MyControl As List(Of Control)
MyControl = New List(Of Control)

For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
    Dim iControl As New Control
    iControl.Text = "Control # " & i
    iControl.Location = New Point(0,0)
    MyControl.Add(iControl)
    i += 1
Next
```

Since I'm not adding them to the form and they have no graphics, would having 1000 controls matter for performance sake? I am using these "hidden" controls sort of like an invisible point for another control to attach itself to, the other control can only attach itself to other controls.

Comment: If you are even thinking of having 1000 controls, you are going down the wrong path.  What's the issue that would cause you to go down this road?

Comment: I probably don't need to have 1000 invisible controls. What I'm trying to do is once the mouse enters an item on another control, I create an invisible control and set the location to that item's location. Then, I'll have a panel popup at that control's location and delete the control once the mouse leave.

Comment: The problem is, the panel that I am using is a custom control that "attach" itself to another control, its location cannot be change, it doesn't even have a location property. Once a control is assign to it, it will show itself above that control

Comment: You are talking about a lot of things we can't see.  Hard to help you.  Forget the performance impact.  Think about the nightmare maintenance issue you have making so many invisible things.  No need to do that.  Just create your control, display it, then dispose of it when you're done.

Comment: I don't need the controls to be displayed, I just need it to be at (X,Y) so that I can attach something else to it.

Comment: In that case, why do you need 1000 invisible controls instead of one that you move around as required?

Comment: That's what I'm going to do yes :)
I was just curious, if I ever did create 1000 invisible controls if the performance would take a big hit

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to "attach" the panel to your invisible control? How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: Whether this would be a performance hit or not depends on what you are doing with these controls and what you need them for. Since they're not added to the form they will never be (re)drawn, so that'll save some CPU. However controls use much more memory than, say, a [`Rectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle), so memory-wise it would cause a certain performance hit if all you need is to store their location and/or size.